# Writing a report/paper etc. - How to deal with citations that have poor English?

Tags: citations, grammar, quotation

I've tried looking for suggestions on the internet to my question but haven't found any useful information.

I'm writing a paper and I'm quoting/citing various books, journals etc. However, I'm coming across of papers that are relevant to my paper that I would like to take quotes from, but were either originally written in another language and have been poorly translated, or were written with bad English to begin with.

Can I quote/cite the papers with corrected English or put the quote as-is? I'm worried if I don't correct the spelling mistakes/poor grammar etc. that the reputation/validity of my paper will be impacted. On the other hand I don't want any corrections I make in the quotes to be considered plagiarism. What should I do?

Edit: I'm writing a literature review section for the paper, if that is relevant.

Comment: What field is this?

Comment: Multiple: Engineering, Electronics, Computer Science, etc.

Comment: It is not common to have verbatim quotations in those fields, regardless of the quality of the original source. Just explain it in your own words.

Comment: Generally, in a lit review, you summarize the findings and relevance of past work. Do you need to quote them verbatim? If so, you can quote the work and then indicate [sic] after the quotation, which lets readers know that the poor language is not your own, but the original author's.

Answer (score 4):

It the material is technical in nature, then you should not be quoting verbatim in the first place.  Instead, you should be paraphrasing the *information* in the paper, which should not be affected by language problems.

If, on the other hand, you actually do need to precisely quote, e.g., for a work on the anthropology of science, then you should use "[sic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)" to indicate that the errors represent a faithful transcription of the original.

An example of its use:

> Sir Puffington was a tireless if somewhat incoherent advocate of faster-than-light travel:
>   "Why should Her Majesty's subjects be so arbitrarily limited, when Vulkins [*sic*] and Star Trucks [*sic*] are not?"

Comment: Did you come up with that quote yourself? :D

Comment: @Michael I only use the finest home-grown organic [word salad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_salad).